# unable to access my USB on ubuntu

Tags: usb

16 GB USB stick is hard to access and use. I created a mount point by typing: mkdir /media/usb. Then typed:
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/usb

But it says:

```
mount: /media/usb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I tried : sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt.
same message.

As to how I knew it was sda, I plugged the USB twice now and one time it was in sda and the other time was in sdb. Either way, I get the same message. But to answer the question, I used this line in the terminal: sudo fdisk -l.

when I use lblsk -f and lblsk -m, I get

```
lblsk: command not found
```

iceblizzard, your solution worked, so thank you. But it has been overwhelming amount of information. This very different from what I'm used to with Windows, do I need to create partitions every time I use a hard drive? What happens to the rest of the space of the hard drive? Thank you in advance. I see there's a lot to learn to use this system.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1255417/edit) to show us how you determined that /dev/sda is the correct path. It's probably not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to mount a disk instead of a partition on the disk, which is not possible. fdisk -l should list partitions such as /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2. Mount those instead; they should work. If there are no partitions, you have not formatted your disk; use GParted or another program to do so. In addition, your usb drive should not be /dev/sda, as /dev/sda is usually the device that contains the root filesystem.

In response to your further questions, no, you do not need to create new partitions every time you use a hard drive; once they are created, they can be used by any computer that can read the filesystem the drive is formatted with. Linux can read ext3/4, xfs, jfs, btrfs, fat, ntfs (after installing ntfs-3g), and others. Unless you specified the size of your partition, the partition should take up all the space on the drive. If your partition does not take up the whole drive, the rest of the space is unallocated and cannot be accessed until it is assigned to a partition.